# What type of assembly do C++ compilers use?

Tags: c++, assembly

So as I'm understood c++ code is comprised of assembly code, and when I compile a program it is read as its assembly equivelent and then run by the compiler.  I'm also understood that assembly syntax and features change from model to model of proccessor.  If this is so, how do compilers manage to compile programs without being littered with bugs? I mean, it can't be possible for a compiler to hold every assembly language variant created, is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're confusing assembly code with machine code. It's not the same. Machine code is what the CPU executes - a byte stream of instructions and data. Assembly is a human readable representation of machine code.

It's indeed true that all C++ code is compiled into machine code, eventually. Yes, the instruction set changes between CPUs and CPU versions. Compilers have the notion of "target architecture" - when you compile, you have an option of specifying one. If you don't, the architecture of the current machine is usually assumed. Yes, compiler vendors have to extend an effort to support every flavor of CPU that they intend to support. Fortunately, there's not that many. Besides, in the C compilation process, code generation is not even the most complex step, so the majority of compiler's own code is not CPU specific.

Some compilers work via assembly - rather than generating machine code, they generate assembly and feed that to an assembler for the final stage of compilation. With that kind of design, your compiler normally assumes a certain flavor of assembler to be present on the system - typically GNU assembler (`as`).

Answer (score 4):

I think you've misunderstood the meaning of "assembly code".

C++ code does not "consist" of assembly code; it consists of, well, C++ code.

A compiler *translates* this C++ code, ultimately into executable machine code that can be run on a computer (usually under the direction of an operating system).

Assembly code is a human-readable symbolic representation of machine code. Typically a line of assmembly code corresponds to a single CPU instruction of machine code. Assembly is a much *lower level* language than C++ (or even C).

Some C++ compilers generate assembly code as an intermediate step; the assembly code is then translated into executable machine code. Other C++ compilers skip that step and generate machine code directly (though they may have an option to produce a human-readable assembly listing).

Typically each compiler accepts input in a single high-level language (C, C++, etc.) and generates output for one CPU (x86, ARM, MIPS, etc). Compilers are commonly designed in phases, so that the portion that processes the high-level input language can be combined with the portion that generates machine-specific code. gcc is designed this way. There are front ends that process a number of different input languages, and code generators that generate code for different CPUs. Thus if you already have an Ada front end and a MIPS back end, it's not *too* difficult to join them together to create an Ada compiler that generates MIPS machine code.

As for how compilers manage to do with without being "littered with bugs", well, it's just a lot of work.